# pandas pivot table where the column contains a string with multiple catogeries

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a data in the form:

```
'cat'     'value'
a         1
a,b       2
a,b,c     3
b,c       2
b         1
```

which I would like to convert using a pivot table:

```
'a'  'b'  'c'
1
2    2
3    3    3
     2    2
     1
```

How do I perform this. If I use the pivot command:

```
df.pivot(columns= 'cat', values = 'value')
```

which yields this result

```
'a' 'a,b' 'a,b,c' 'b,c' 'b' 
1
     2
           3
                   2
                        1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with **[`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)** and multiply the `value` column (*then replace 0 with nan if necessary*)

```
df['cat'].str.get_dummies(",").mul(df['value'],axis=0).replace(0,np.nan)
```

---

```
     a    b    c
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  2.0  2.0  NaN
2  3.0  3.0  3.0
3  NaN  2.0  2.0
4  NaN  1.0  NaN
```

Comment: both answers are good but i used this version.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.explode()` after transforming the string into a list, and then pivot it normally:

```
df['cat'] = df['cat'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('cat').pivot_table(index=df.explode('cat').index,columns='cat',values='value')
```

This outputs:

```
cat a   b   c
0   1.0 NaN NaN
1   2.0 2.0 NaN
2   3.0 3.0 3.0
3   NaN 2.0 2.0
4   NaN 1.0 NaN
```

You can then reset, or rename the index if you wish for it to not be named `cat`.

Comment: I had  `df = df.explode('cat').pivot(columns='cat', values='value')`, maybe simpler if its the same as your pivot?

Comment: No, because the values get aggregated and a single row is outputed :)

Comment: The output is the same as yours, at least for this example.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just noticed you were using `pivot` whereas I was using `pivot_table`. Yes, you are correct, you can use `pivot` too.